# Message: Call to undefined method Main::check_marital_status() Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem getting data in the model

I want to get the data of `marital_status` table from the database

Here's the error

> Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to undefined method Main::check_marital_status()
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\hlurb\application\controllers\Main.php
>
> Line Number: 61

Controller

```
public function dealer_register(){

    $this->load->model('AccountModel');
    $data['marital_status'] = $this->check_marital_status()->result();

    $this->load->view('register/dealer_register', $data);
}
```

Model

```
public function check_marital_status(){

    $sql="SELECT * FROM marital_status";
        return $this->db->query($sql);


}
```

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
Syntax (loading model) –

$this->load->model(Model-class-name);

Syntax (call model method) –

$this->[Model-class-name]->method-name();

public function dealer_register(){

    $this->load->model('accountmodel');
    $data['marital_status'] = $this->accountmodel->check_marital_status()->result();

    $this->load->view('register/dealer_register', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

call your model.like this.
//controller

```
public function dealer_register(){

    $this->load->model('AccountModel');
    $data['marital_status'] = $this->model_name->check_marital_status();

    $this->load->view('register/dealer_register', $data);
}
```

//model

```
public function check_marital_status(){
$this->db->select('marital_status.*');
return $this->db->get('marital_status')->result();
}
```

Comment: New errors occurred mate. 

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Main::$db

and 

Message: Call to a member function select() on null

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\hlurb\application\models\AccountModel.php

Comment: load your database in construct function.
  function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

Comment: Got it mate. I just forgot do declare the database in autoload